# Node's request does not pass POST requests using pipe

Tags: node.js, express, node-request

Proxy written using node/express and request fails to pipe POST calls, GET seems to work:

```
var pipeToTrustedZone = function(req, res){ 
    getEnrichedHeaders(req,function(err, headers){
    req.headers = headers;
    var url = proxiedServerPath + req.originalUrl;
    console.log(req.method+" TOWARDS");
    log.info(url);
    req.pipe(request({qs:req.query, uri: url })).pipe(res);
    });
}
```

The above code executes get requests just fine placed as a middleware in an express router, however on POST the proxiedServer never receives the message.

Any idea why the above does not work?

Also my app is using body parser middlewares since not all endpoints are to be proxied:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to both set request `headers` in the object passed to `request()` *and* set the appropriate headers on `res`. That means you won't be able to simply make it one-liner. For example:

```
req.pipe(request({
  qs: req.query,
  uri: url,
  headers: req.headers
})).on('response', function(pres) {
  res.writeHead(pres.statusCode, pres.headers);
  pres.pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: still no success, could it be that the bodyParser interferes?

Comment: Yes, that would affect it. It may be easier to just move routes and/or body parsing middleware around so that they're not executed for your proxy route?